# R plotting frequency distribution

Tags: r, plot

I know that we normally do in this way:

```
x=c(rep(0.3,100),rep(0.5,700))
plot(table(x))
```

However, we can only get a few dots or vertical lines in the graph.

**What should I do if I want 100 dots above 0.3 and 700 dots above 0.5?**

Comment: You mean instead of the line from (0.5,0) to (0.5,700) you want 700 dots, and instead of the line from (0.3,0) to (0.3,100) you want 100 dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
x <- c(rep(.3,100), rep(.5, 700))
y <- c(seq(0,1, length.out=100), seq(0,1,length.out=700))
plot(x,y)
```

**edit:** (following OP's comment)

In that case, something like this should work.

```
x <- rep(seq(1, 10)/10, seq(100, 1000, by=100))
x.t <- as.matrix(table(x))
y <- unlist(apply(x.t, 1, function(x) seq(1,x)))
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: yes, but the actual situation will be more complicated.
x will be a vector containing a lot of numeric values. I want to plot the frequency in dots (if 0.1 occurs 100 times, plot 100 dots above 0.1)

Comment: @Cathy what is the difference with `plot(table(x),lwd=6)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can lay with the `linetype` and `linewidth` settings...

```
plot(table(x),lty=3,lwd=0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: @Arun yes ...how to distinguish between 100 and 30..or 500.dots..visually (assuming the dots are the same shape, no jitter option , no aplha blending).

Comment: I thought the same as agustudy before. but i think it will look better is the number matches the frequency/\/\
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

For smaller numbers (counts) you can use `stripchart` with `method="stack"` like this:

```
stripchart(c(rep(0.3,10),rep(0.5,70)), pch=19, method="stack", ylim=c(0,100))
```

But stripchart does not work for 700 dots.

---

*Edit:*

The `dots()` function from the package [TeachingDemos](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TeachingDemos/index.html) is probably what you want:

```
 require(TeachingDemos)
 dots(x)
```